# Progress 4GL - How to convert data from UTF-8 to UTF-8 BOM?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Just to know from UTF-8 to UTF-8 BOM conversion. Below query I use and its not giving results as expected. correct me if I am wrong.

```
define stream m_str.
output stream m_str to value("C:\inetpub\file.txt") convert target "UTF-8".
/*Data goes here*/
output stream m_str close.
```

Comment: Why do you need the BOM? What is the input data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`google site:progress.com output utf-8 bom`

https://community.progress.com/s/article/P110483

> UTF-8 encoding in most cases does not require a byte-order mark (and in a number of cases forbids it), therefore it is not written to the file.
> This does cause issues with the few use cases where the BOM is required.

> Workaround
> The BOM can be added manually using the PUT CONTROL statement:

```
OUTPUT TO c:\temp\js.html CONVERT TARGET "UTF-8".
PUT CONTROL "~357~273~277". /* BOM for UTF-8 */

/* actual output goes here */

OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

For clarification, [~nnn](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/pdsoe/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.openedge.pdt.langref.help/rfi1424920643769.html) is an octal character, so:

- 357 -> 0xEF
- 273 -> 0xBB
- 277 -> 0xBF

Which corresponds with the [Byte Order Mark byte sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) `EF BB BF`.

Combining the above two links, you can also provide the less archaic Unicode character U+FEFF BYTE ORDER MARK:

```
output to file.txt convert target 'utf-8'.
put control '~ufeff'. // BOM

// actual output goes here

output close.
```